# Which one of the following are true?[CSIR-June 2017]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left|a_n-a_{n-1}\right|<\infty $, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n,x\in \mathbb R$ is convergent.

(a)nowhere on $\mathbb R$

(b)Everywhere on $\mathbb R$

(c) On some set containing $(-1,1)$

(d)Only on $(-1,1)$

My Try

(a) False, $a_n=1/n$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n,x\in \mathbb (-1,1)$ is convergent

(b) False,  $a_n=1/n$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n,x\in \mathbb (-1,1)$ is convergent. Not converges everywhere.

(c) I think (c) is also false, $a_n=1/2^n$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/2^n,x\in \mathbb (-1/2,1/2)$. which is not an interval containing (-1,1)

(d)False, $a_n=2^n$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^nx^n,x\in \mathbb (-2,2)$

Comment: You are not justifying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n-a_{n-1}|<\infty$ in any of your examples at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for (d) is not valid because $a_n=2^{n}$ does not satisfy the hypothesis. Note that $|a_n-a_m| \leq |a_n-a_{n+1}|+...+|a_{m-1}-a_m|$ for $n >m$. Conclude that $(a_n)$ Ia Cauchy sequence, hence bounded. It follows that the series $\sum a_n x^{n}$ converges in $(-1,1)$. Being a  power series it converges in some interval containing $(-1,1)$. Other parts of your answer are correct.

Comment: I understood $a_n$ is cauchy,  How do that impliy $\sum a_nx^n$ converges in (-1,1)?

Comment: For any bounded sequence $(a_n)$ this series converges for $|x|<1$. To see  this compare  it with the geometric series $\sum C|x|^{n}$ where $C$ is a bound for $|a_n|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using the root criterion as follows.

First note that the sequence (a_n) is convergent:

- $a_n = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)\stackrel{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k+1}-a_k|<\infty}{\Longrightarrow} \exists \lim_{n\to \infty }|a_n| =L\geq 0$

Now, there are two cases for the radius of convergence $\rho$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$:
$$L>0 \stackrel{\forall n>N_{\epsilon:\;}0<\sqrt[n]{L-\epsilon} < \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < \sqrt[n]{L+\epsilon}}{\Rightarrow} \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1\Rightarrow \rho = 1$$
$$L=0 \stackrel{\forall n>N_{\epsilon:\;}0\leq \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1}{\Rightarrow} \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq 1\Rightarrow \rho \geq 1$$

So, the radius of convergence is at least $1$, hence the series converges on some set containing $(-1,1)$.